Как подключить ввод информации в wordpress и отпрвку с помощью php?
Как подключить ввод информации в wordpress и отпрвку по tcp/udp с помощью php?
Со вторым ещё понятно(вставлял через сниппет):
$remote_ip = 'smth';
$remote_port = smth;

// Create a TCP socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

// Connect to the remote server
if (socket_connect($socket, $remote_ip, $remote_port)) {
    // Data to send
    $message = "Hello, this is a message from PHP!";

    // Send the message
    socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message));

    // Close the socket
    socket_close($socket);
} else {
    echo "Unable to connect to the remote server.";
}

Но как подключить ввод данных(пытался через Contact Form 7), этого не знаю. Примерно должно выглядеть так(то есть пишешь информацию, нажимаешь отправить и он отправляется по TCP/UDP)


Ничего не понятно.. что такое "отпрвку по php"? Как, какой информации, куда, зачем.. зачем вообще что-то "подключать" ? Задачи какие? (комментарии есть из коробки)

@SeVlad Отправка с помощью php по tcp, введённой информации

Ajax в WordPress
